# saving a single value to the django datastore

Tags: django, django-models

In django, what is the right way to save a 'single' value to the datastore?

For example, I want to save and retrieve a number value which gets changed from time to time.

Do I need to wrap this number into a class?

```
class Numba(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField( )
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Django entity classes represents tables in the database. You can't store anything in the database outside a table. You can wrap this number inside a model class and store it in the database, you may also create something like `settings_table` in the database to include everything you need to store that doesn't represent an specific entity so it won't be a single number or you can store the *magic number* in a file within the filesystem using normal python I/O.